# What are the differences in performance between synchronous and asynchronous JavaScript script loading?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

My question is simply: what are the differences in performance between synchronous and asynchronous JavaScript script loading?

From what I've gathered synchronous code blocks the loading of a page and/or rest of the code from executing. This happens at **two levels**.

First, at the level of the script actually loading, and secondly, within the JavaScript code itself.

For example, on the page:

Synchronous: `<script src="demo_async.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Asynchronous: `<script async src="demo_async.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

**Edit:** Removed invalid code examples

So what really is the difference in performance from using these different loading methods and JavaScript patterns?

Comment: What is the last example? You can't have a function within an argument list of a function declaration.

Comment: Your "self-executing" code is just some weird invalid syntax. And why are you giving the "async" version different code to execute? That muddies the comparison. Anyway, IMO, performance difference *(if any)* is irrelevant. You use whichever one is needed for the situation.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token function

Comment: Sorry guys, its my poor attempt at an asynchronous function. Could you please post an example of an async function for me to update in the question please?

Comment: Keep in mind the difference between performance (things happening faster) and perceived performance (things appearing to happen faster to a user, usually by changing load order).

Comment: There's no such thing as an async function, at least not that can be created with simple JavaScript syntax. Though there are implementation provided methods that may behave asynchronously, like `setTimeout`. These methods generally accept a callback function.

Comment: @IHateLazy I think your comment is misleading. Asynchronous JavaScript programming is very common nowadays. There are just a lack of good, simple, understandable examples. They all use callbacks to nest functions as the last parameter of the argument list.

Comment: @jan-dvorak - I believe you are wrong also. In JavaScript functions within the parameters are very common - they are known as `callbacks`. This highlights the need for this topic of callbacks and asynchronous JavaScript programming in general to have more clarity.

Comment: @jasdeepkhalsa I was referring to `function(/* this argument list */){...}`, which is indeed illegal.

Comment: @JanDvorak - Yes, I guess you're referring to when a function is setup you can't use a function as a parameter. But I was referring to when you use a function which has this callback setup, you CAN pass a function into it as a parameter. Like in this example: http://jsbin.com/ozuloq/1/edit

Comment: @jasdeepkhalsa: It's not at all misleading. Since you're not using any host methods to achieve your "async" version, it's worth noting that *nothing* in the JavaScript language is asynchronous. The only async capabilities are provided by add-ons in a host environment, and `setTimeout` is one example of that.

Comment: ...and not all of them accept a callback as a "last parameter of the arguments list". There are various ways in which they accept the callback.

Comment: ...and just because a function accepts a function argument, doesn't mean that the argument is invoked asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments guys! Really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first question/snippet, its more about *control-flow* than performance. Performance is just an implicit consequence there.

`<script>` tags will, traditionally, *block* the *HTML Renderer* if they are encountered. That means, if you load a *huge* javascript file with a blocking `<script>` tag at the very top of the markup, a user would not see any progress on the page as long as the script is getting loaded and evaluated.

In contrary, if we flag the `<script>` tag with attributes like *async* and/or *defer*, the browser will no longer stop the *HTML render process*, but load and evaluate the script block *asyncronously*. How an implementation does this, is not on your concern (whether it uses real threads under the hood or just sequentially process it).

---

Your second snippet is not really *asyncronous* code. Its just *function expressions* which invoke themselfs. That is still considered *syncronous execution*.

Comment: What is considered an asynchronous function then?

Comment: @jasdeepkhalsa: any method (most of the time, native methods), which return the control-flow immediately (=non-blocking). Popular examples are *XMLHttpRequests*, *setTimeout*, *setInterval* on the clientside.

Answer (score 0):

When you do load things asynchronously the browser meanwhile can load other parts of the page itself.

besides that if you just compare the load of the script it self, both methods are equal in performance.

Comment: Do you have any test data to prove they are equal in performance? I thought it was generally understood that asynchronous is faster. I may be wrong and stand to be corrected.

Comment: not for your example. but take node.js. write then an implementation for e.g. reading a directory's content. do an implementation for sync and async.